# What's the word for luck in gamers vocabulary?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

You know sometimes gamers use this word when they describe a person having a tremendous amount of luck in a game esp an FPS game like counter strike. It's not "coincidence" or "lucky" but there is something else. The vocabulary class might be an urban one like "smurfing", etc..

Like out of a sudden, a player could become really good when the rest of his games weren't.

Comment: It's called hacks.

Comment: @Blubberguy22 They spell it 'hax'.

Comment: hax isn't quite there yet. There is this word that means like "super lucky" or "by a random stroke of luck" or to be more precise it is like all the forces of the universe is for that guy for that specific golden moment....
i can't really recall it but once I hear it or see it I will get "aha that's it, that's the word"

edit: the word may not be that too urban

Comment: It doesn't totally convey the feeling of a rare explosion of ability, but the player is often said to be "hot", or "on a hot streak".

Comment: **PWNAGE**? Maybe **Winning streak**?

Comment: I believe the OP already figured out the word he was looking for. It was ***fluke***. Maybe the comments got deleted...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is as descriptive as the term you are looking for, but I have heard this coined colloquially as 'magic'. It seems to have the connotation of being a magnificent outburst, an inexplicable coincidence, or tremendous luck.

"What is this magic?"

"He's been using magic this round."

"How did he even see me?" "He didn't, it was magic."

Comment: Question: Do gamers ever use "sorcery," as in "What is this sorcery?"

Comment: @NickWeinberg If you want to ask a follow-up question, you should post it as a question.